# sql query to compare column name to column data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What I am looking for is how I could go about running a query to select

```
SELECT 'text' FROM 'some_table' 
WHERE 'text' = 'some_column_name'
```

I have looked and searched, and may be searching with the wrong information, but I have been unable to find anything of the sort.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The question is somewhat unclear, but I'll assume that you are trying to get the values of one particular column.  And looking at the column names of a particular table, you want a list of all columns whose name is the same as the returned value. Then something like below might be a good start.

```
SELECT
    T.ColumnName, -- will show the value of the column
    C.Object_name([object_id]), --will show the name of the table
    C.name -- will show the name of the column that matched the column value
FROM 
    SchemaName.TableName T
INNER JOIN  
    Sys.Columns C 
ON 
    T.ColumnName= C.name 
WHERE
    [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('SchemaName.TableName')
```

If you want to compare the value of the column to the column names in a different table or any tables, you simply need to change or delete the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500), @text nvarchar(200) = 'sometext';

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @text + ' FROM some_table WHERE ' + @text + ' = ''' + @text + ''''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Be sure to read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).